# Transpose Tiff files from folder based on parameter (Hyphen) to CSV

Tags: excel, vba, batch-file

I have the folder which contains `tiff` files, in between few images are marked with "-", which indicates transpose parameter.Once it encounter"-" the files reflecting below them are transposed until another "-" is triggered.

```
001-001.tif
```

---

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

set root=D:\Testing\100
set csv=E:\JOE\Transpose1.csv

set line=-
set curpath=
set new=
>nul copy nul: %csv%

for /f %%F in ('dir /s/b %root%\*.tif') do (
  if not "!curpath!" == "%%~dpF" set new=y
  set fname=%%~nxF
  if not "!fname:-=!" == "!fname!" set new=y

  if defined new (
    if defined line echo !line!>> %csv%
    set line=%%~dpF
    set new=
  )

  set line=!line!,%%~nxF
  set curpath=%%~dpF
)
if defined line echo !line!>> %csv%
```

---

```
002.tif
003.tif
004-004.tif
```

I have the code which was good enough to go but recently noticed with error output.

[image: code]

[image: Transpose output]

Comment: Please paste those code here, instead of put them in pictures.

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54683986/edit) into your question please. And you can select the codes, and click the `{}` button on the editor to format them.

Comment: ok, almost there. What is the question?

Comment: As per the sample enclosed, the transpose is happening in reverse order, check the sample with " correct transpose" is what the result should be.

Comment: So you specifically want to transpose each hyphened file with a non hyphened file, but one numeric value higher? i.e `005-005 -> 006` ?

Comment: Not exactly, The folder contains multiple tiff files.These are partial legal documents in serial order.Every first page is marked with "Hyphen" and rest of the file names are transposed horizontally it could be 1 file or 50 files. The minute it encounter "Hyphen" it should start from the next row.

Comment: Then I am not clear on what you need? what should the results be, what bases the results on what you expect?

Comment: in simple line, the minute the file encounter "Hyphen" it will start fresh from the next row of csv file. There could be any no of files between both the "Hyphen"

Comment: Ok, I am going to give you sample input, you give me expected output, then I will figure out. `001-001` `002` `003` `004-004` `005` `006-006` `007`

Comment: My apologies! if i couldn't explain. If you look at the example 006-006.tif is marked with Hyphen. The file no 007.tif does not contain Hyphen. That means 006-006.tif and 007.tif is transposed and shown on row 5. The next scenario , the file encounter hyphen 007-007.tif, so it indicates the result to be populated in the next row. ie row 6

Comment: row 1 001-001 002 003 
row 2 004-004 005 
row 3 006-006 007

Comment: ah ok, now I get it :)

Comment: do me a favour, in your for loop, change to `'dir /s/b /on %root%\*.tif'` and let me know the results?

Comment: Yes ! i pulled a folder it went perfect as desired.

Comment: ok, are you sure it works as expected? If so, I can post an answer with explanation, else if not, I can relook at it.

Comment: is there a way, where i can move this files to a specific folder in a go E:\JOE\122\ 0051-0051.tif 0052.tif 0053.tif

Comment: yes there is, which ones? only the hyphened files?

Comment: All the files which are transposed in a row to a new specific folder

Comment: row 1 001-001 002 003 to folder 1
row 2 004-004 005 to folder 2
row 3 006-006 007 to folder 3    from your example

Answer (score 0):

By running `dir /?` you will see the order switch `/o` by forcing it by name, it will change the order as expected.

By Default order will be as:

```
006-006
006
007-007
008-008
008
```

by doing `dir /on` you force it to order by name:

```
006
006-006
007-007
008
008-008
```

Therefore we simply change the `dir` command in the for loop:

```
('dir /s/b /on %root%\*.tif')
```

Then, I think to do the move of the files, it would be simplest not to change your script. Perhaps just run a loop at the end of the file to move the files, this demo does it by incrementing the number to a folder, but you would need to adjust it to your need as it will not store the last `!cnt!` value for the next run.

So this we will need at the end of the script:

```
timeout 2>nul
set /a cnt=1
for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=," %%i in (%csv%) do (
    mkdir %%ifolder!cnt!>nul
    move %%i%%j %%ifolder!cnt!
    move %%i%%k %%ifolder!cnt!
    set /a cnt+=1
)
```

The for loop above reads through the csv file, splits it into 3 tokens (%%i - %%k) and use `,` delimeter. Then we simply use the tokens to perform the move command to move the files. So it pretty much splits it as such from your csv:

```
D:\somedir,007-007.tif,008.tif
```

to

```
D:\somedir   --> %%i
007-007.tif  --> %%j
008.tif      --> %%k
```

You can get more information on this by running `for /?` from cmd.exe

Comment: Tried with move of files, but could not define where to move.Hence if we could define a destination path in code will be helpful,as per csv.

Comment: row 1 001-001 002 003 to MAIN FOLDER/SUB folder 1 
row 2 004-004 005 to MAIN FOLDER/SUB folder 2 
row 3 006-006 007 to MAIN FOLDER/SUB folder 3

E:\JOE\120\FOLDER 1
E:\JOE\121\FOLDER 2

Comment: Probably one final update is appreciated , the file to the folder is omitted if the row sequence contains more than 2 files.row 1 001-001(available) 002(available) 003(ommited) to MAIN FOLDER/SUB folder 1

Comment: Also let me know what logic is applied here so to understand better

Comment: Added explanation to the answer.

Comment: Hi, I have tried with Tokens=* to have all the files in a row to move to folder, but with error.As these folders needs to be created in destination path instead of source.

Comment: What is the destination path?

Comment: E:\JOE\120\row 1 001-001 002 003 to E:\JOE_OUTPUT\120\Sub Folder 1

Comment: for /F %i in ("E:\JOE_OUTPUT\folder1") do convert %i "E:\JOE_OUTPUT\folder1\*.tif" "E:\JOE\120\001-0001.tif"

Comment: I have further added a code which will combine the tiff files in sub folder to a master folder. I need to know how to incorporate in the original code, the second part is using imagemagik function

Comment: HI Barnard, any further thoughts on this